# XSLT - Need help for transformation into vaguely JSON-like format

Tags: json, xslt, abap

I have a requirement where I want to convert my Internal Table data into JSON format.

Lets assume my internal table name is ZEMPLOYEE and the fields in it are EMPID,ENAME,ESAL.
Normal Call Transformation will convert it into the below format.

> Data-[ {EMPID:101,ENAME:'ABCD',ESAL:100} , {EMPID:102,ENAME:'EFGH',ESAL:200}, {EMPID:103,ENAME:'IJKL',ESAL:300} ]

But my requirement is the output format should look like this:

> Data-[ {EMPID,ENAME,ESAL} , { 101,ABCD,100 } , {102 , EFGH , 200} , {103,IJKL,300} ]...

Where the first curly braces will contain the fields of my table and remaining curly braces contain the actual data.

Can anybody please help me achieve the above output using XSLT Transformation or Simple Transformation?

Comment: Please post the input xml as well as the xslt you have tried

Comment: HI Saurav,
This is the XML I have...

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
- <FLIGHT_TABLE>
- <ZSCARR_LINE>
  <CARRID>AA</CARRID> 
  <CARRNAME>American Airlines</CARRNAME> 
  <CURRCODE>USD</CURRCODE> 
  </ZSCARR_LINE>
- <ZSCARR_LINE>
  <CARRID>AB</CARRID> 
  <CARRNAME>Air Berlin</CARRNAME> 
  <CURRCODE>EUR</CURRCODE> 
  </ZSCARR_LINE>
- <ZSCARR_LINE>
  <CARRID>AC</CARRID> 
  <CARRNAME>Air Canada</CARRNAME> 
  <CURRCODE>CAD</CURRCODE> 
  </ZSCARR_LINE>
- <ZSCARR_LINE>
  <CARRID>AF</CARRID> 
  <CARRNAME>Air France</CARRNAME> 
  <CURRCODE>EUR</CURRCODE> 
  </ZSCARR_LINE>
</FLIGHT_TABLE>

Comment: from where are you getting this "101,ABCD,100" data??

Comment: I might be wrong, but is that valid (and/or sensible) JSON at all? There should be key-value pairs inside the curly braces...

Comment: @vwegert..
Yes, Valid JSON will be in Key-Value pairs....since the table columns wont change I want to keep them in the first curly braces...and then I want to keep the data...so that the memory used for storing the Key Names will be saved..

Comment: @Saurav...
This is the Program...
*******
DATA: lt_table TYPE TABLE OF zscarr_line.
DATA: xml_string TYPE xstring.
SELECT * FROM scarr INTO CORRESPONDING FIELDS OF TABLE lt_table.

CALL TRANSFORMATION zflight SOURCE flight_table = lt_table
                            RESULT XML xml_string.

In the above line.....XML_STRING will contain the XML data...I want to send that XML_STRING to CALL TRANSFORMATION (MY_ID). where that XML should change into my intended output...

Comment: @kishorebabu Then you won't be converting to JSON, but to YAIDF. (Your Arbitrarily Incopatible Data Format).

Comment: @vwegert... 
So for converting it into my custom defined format...I need to use the XSL Transformation only right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you show us is much closer to CSV than to JSON. Try something like:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text" encoding="UTF-8"/>

<xsl:template match="/*">
    <!-- header -->
    <xsl:text>Data-[{</xsl:text>
    <xsl:for-each select="*[1]/*">
        <xsl:value-of select="local-name()"/>
        <xsl:if test="position()!=last()">
            <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
    <xsl:text>},</xsl:text>

    <!-- data -->
    <xsl:for-each select="*">
        <xsl:text>{</xsl:text>
        <xsl:for-each select="*">
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            <xsl:if test="position()!=last()">
                <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
        <xsl:text>}</xsl:text>
        <xsl:if test="position()!=last()">
            <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
    <xsl:text>]</xsl:text>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When applied to a **well-formed(!) input** example:

```
<FLIGHT_TABLE>
  <ZSCARR_LINE>
    <CARRID>AA</CARRID>
    <CARRNAME>American Airlines</CARRNAME>
    <CURRCODE>USD</CURRCODE>
  </ZSCARR_LINE>
  <ZSCARR_LINE>
    <CARRID>AB</CARRID>
    <CARRNAME>Air Berlin</CARRNAME>
    <CURRCODE>EUR</CURRCODE>
  </ZSCARR_LINE>
  <ZSCARR_LINE>
    <CARRID>AC</CARRID>
    <CARRNAME>Air Canada</CARRNAME>
    <CURRCODE>CAD</CURRCODE>
  </ZSCARR_LINE>
  <ZSCARR_LINE>
    <CARRID>AF</CARRID>
    <CARRNAME>Air France</CARRNAME>
    <CURRCODE>EUR</CURRCODE>
  </ZSCARR_LINE>
</FLIGHT_TABLE>
```

the **result** will be:

```
Data-[{CARRID,CARRNAME,CURRCODE},{AA,American Airlines,USD},{AB,Air Berlin,EUR},{AC,Air Canada,CAD},{AF,Air France,EUR}]
```

Comment: Thanks Michael for your response..The above code is not giving the output at all...This is my code
DATA: lt_table TYPE TABLE OF zscarr_line.
DATA: xml_string TYPE xstring.
SELECT * FROM scarr INTO CORRESPONDING FIELDS OF TABLE lt_table.
CALL TRANSFORMATION zflight SOURCE flight_table = lt_table
                            RESULT XML xml_string.
lref_json_writer = cl_sxml_string_writer=>create( type = if_sxml=>co_xt_json ).
call Transformation zkxslt Source Xml xml_string
                           Result Xml xml_string.
In ZKXSLT ID, I kept the code you posted,but it is not giving the output.

Comment: @kishorebabu The above XSLT code transforms an XML input document to the requested format - see:http://xsltransform.net/bFDb2C8 If you're having problems initiating an XSL transformation within your application, post a separate question about that. -- P.S. Please don't post code in comments - edit your question instead..

Comment: The above code which you mentioned has worked for me...but how can I obtain the original XML file from the output which we get. Which approach should I follow.

Comment: @kishorebabu "*Which approach should I follow.*" I don't really know. Any tool that can parse **text** and output it as XML would do, I suppose.